# Mensaje de "Cargando..." con jQuery.post (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando este tipo de envió de datos a través de jQuery.post, ¿En que lugar coloco una imagen de loading... o algún mensaje mientras devuelve algo la función?

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es truco esta en usar [ajaxStart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) y [ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/).

Estos eventos son invocados por jQuery cada vez que comienza/termina una solicitud ajax. Ya sea que se hagan por los métodos `post`, `ajax`, `load`, ..

Es muy util pues si hay varias solicitudes ajax en paralelo, el evento `ajaxStop` es invocado cuando termina la ultima solicitud . Y el evento `ajaxStart` no se repite si ya hay una solicitud en progreso.

```
$(function() {

  // tu elemento que quieres activar.
  var cargando = $("#cargando");

  // evento ajax start
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    cargando.show();
  });

  // evento ajax stop
  $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    cargando.hide();
  });

  // cualquier llamada ajax
  $.post("ajax/test.html", function(data) {
    $(".result").html(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

En el script que planteas la función es un callback y se ejecuta cuando suceda un evento (en este caso que el post termine), como vos lo querés hacer en ese momento alcanza con actuar fuera del callback.

```
$.post("ajax/test.html", function(data) {
  $(".result").html(data); // esto se ejecuta cuando el post termine
});
$(".result").html('loading'); // esto se ejecuta después de hacer el post
```

Si lo que necesitas es hacer esto para cualquier AJAX la respuesta de @rnd es mejor.