# Gif "Cargando" mientras se genera una consulta php mysql

Tags: php

Buenos dias.
Tengo una pagina que envia por formulario post 3 variables, la misma es capturada por otra pagina y realiza una consulta y genera una tabla con datos de mysql.
Actualmente la tabla tiene 140.000 registros por lo que al momento de enviar los datos tarda unos 20 seg en armar todo.
Necesito que me guien para mostrar un gif que diga cargando al momento de dar click en el boton de enviar hasta que la otra pagina este generada.
Encontre ejemplos pero el efecto lo hace cuando la pagina ya se genero por lo que estoy esperando 20 seg y dsp hace el gif y el fade para mostrar lo que haya dentro de un div.
¿Me dan una mano? ¿Con que se hace o que tengo que buscar para poder aprenderlo?
Al dar click en buscar que ya me aparezca un gif "Cargando" hasta que la pagina siguiente pueda mostrar la tabla.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hay varios ejemplos aquí en SOes, buscaste antes de publicar tu pregunta?

Comment: Si me guias como buscarlo o que usar para poder saber que buscar te lo agradeceria, si consulte fue porque no se como buscar siquiera lo que necesito hacer.

Comment: Tendrías que usar Jquery o Javascript. [Mostrar gif con jquery y ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88279/por-qu%c3%a9-mi-gif-cargando-no-se-muestra-correctamente-con-ajax) [Otra relacionada a la muestra de gif con ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61174/mostrar-imagen-gig-con-jquery)

Comment: [Mensaje de cargando con jquery post y ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5058/mensaje-de-cargando-con-jquery-post-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $btn = $('#btn');
  var $data = $('.data');
  var $loader = $('.loader');


  $btn.click(function(){

    $.ajax({
     // ejemplo url
     url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cwjKzYsDTm?indent=2',
     method: 'GET',
     beforeSend: function() {
      // aquí puedes poner el código paraque te muestre el gif
      $data.html("");
      $loader.show();
     }
    }).done(function(resp){
      setTimeout(function(){
       $loader.hide();
       $data.html(resp[0].about);
      }, 5000);
    }).fail(function(err){
      $loader.hide();
      alert(err);
    })
    return;
  });

});
```

```css
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    display: none;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
   <button id="btn">Enviar</button>

  
  <div class="data"></div>
  <div class="loader"></div> 
</div>
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo, adaptalo a tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Es sensillo compañero lo que necesitas es que cuando le dan **click** al boton de enviar con **JavaScript** o **Jquery** muestras o escondes el gif.

Claro antes de eso, tienes que crear toda la estructura o colocar el Gif y con css ocultarlo con una opacidad de **0** o con un **display: none** (lo que no rompa tu estructura).

Ya cuando tengas la consulta vuelves a ocultar tu gif o tu animacion con el mismo  **JavaScript** o **Jquery** (lo que estes usando).

Cualquier duda me comentas.

Quieres ver unos cuantos spinner de cargando revisa este enlace:

https://codepen.io/tag/spinner/

Si quieres ver como funciona ve a este enlace:

Click AQUI!! [Mostrar Gif - click](https://codepen.io/weboneando/pen/WEBdOE/).

```js
$(function()
  {
    $('#target').submit(function( event ) {
      /*Previene que el form se envien*/
      event.preventDefault();
      /* Muestra el gif*/
      $('#loading').show();
      /* deshabilita el boton para que no se envien muchas peticiones*/
      $('.btn').addClass( 'disabled' );
      
      alert(" Ya puedes enviar lo que necesites por Ajax o validar lo que necesites")
    });
});
```

Comment: Procura compartir algo de código de ejemplo para la solución.

Comment: Lo que usted sugeria ya se agrego